# Finding multiple patterns using findall funtion in Python

Tags: python, string, findall

Is there any other way of finding multiple patterns using findall instead of just adding functions together? Im just starting with python...

```
txt = "UUUUUUUUUUUUUUCUUCUUCUUCUUCUUC"

print ("Phenylalanine " ) + str(len(re.findall(r'UUC',txt)) + len(re.findall(r'UUU',txt)))
```

Which is giving a correct answer 10 matches but thats a hard way, just what happens when there are more patterns:

```
print ("Leucine " ) + str(len(re.findall(r'UUA',txt)) + len(re.findall(r'UUG',txt)) + len(re.findall(r'CUU',txt)) + len(re.findall(r'CUC',txt)) + len(re.findall(r'CUA',txt)) + len(re.findall(r'CUG',txt)))
```

thought about:

```
list1 = ['UUU', 'UUC', 'UUA', 'UUG', 'CUU', 'CUC', 'CUA', 'CUG' ];
list2 = ['Phenylalanine', 'Leucine'];
```

But how to match them together?

Or something like:

```
print ("Phenylalanine " ) + str(len(re.findall(r'UUC' **and** 'UUU',txt)))
```

but /and/ and /or/ are not giving me the right answer

I have 64 patterns to match with 23 names, how to do it much easier? how with a table?
Thank you

Comment: Click edit post, select the code snippets, and press ctrl+k.

Please give us an idea as to what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello I was thinking about creating two lists: one with names, and the other one with patterns  `code`list1 = ['UUU', 'UUC'];
list2 = ['Phenylalanine', and so on ]`code`

Comment: You should definitely put that in your question, and then tell us what happens when you run it.

Comment: Well its giving me the correct answer, but thats a lot work when you have to deal with many patterns like:  `code`
print ("Leucine " ) + str(len(re.findall(r'UUA',txt)) + len(re.findall(r'UUG',txt)) + len(re.findall(r'CUU',txt)) + len(re.findall(r'CUC',txt)) + len(re.findall(r'CUA',txt)) + len(re.findall(r'CUG',txt))) `code`

Comment: For now, just write that you did the above so far in your question, and wait. honestly that's the best I can do for you right now. Just every few minutes, make a small edit to bump your post to the top of the homepage so other more experienced python users can answer your question. I'm rusty with python :)

Answer (score -1):

So, one way is to iterate over all the items in list1:

```
sequences = {
    'Phenylalanine' : [r'UUU', r'UUC'],
    'Leucine' : [r'UUA', r'UUG', r'CUU', r'CUC', r'CUA', r'CUG' ]
}    
for name, sequence_list in sequences.items():
    print (name, str(sum(len(re.findall(i, txt)) for i in sequence_list)))
```

The above method isn't great, because it calls `findall` multiple times.

The other method if you want to parse the string only once will be to use regex's OR. `(abc|cde)` will match abc or cde. But regex goes more complicated, and I'm not sure if it will give you the same results.

Simple method through regex would be: `len(re.findall(r"(UUC|UUU)", txt))`

If you have a list like the above `sequences` it would be like:

```
sequences = {
    'Phenylalanine' : [r'UUU', r'UUC'],
    'Leucine' : [r'UUA', r'UUG', r'CUU', r'CUC', r'CUA', r'CUG' ]
}    
for name, sequence_list in sequences.items():
    print (name, str(len(re.findall("(" + "|".join(sequence_list) + ")", txt)))
```

Both the above methods give me:

```
Leucine 5
Phenylalanine 10
```

NOTE : Your overall problem seems to be one of those DNA sequencing problems. I suggest you use a pre existing library for something like this, as it would get more complex if you're going to work indepth in this.